# JSON object not working/ conecting

Tags: java, android, json, xml

When I run my app I can't see my JSON data. 
It throws an exception where it says this

`Toast.makeText(this, "can't execute http request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

```
public class IsstatusActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.isstatus);
        TextView latCor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Coordinates);
        latCor.setText(getJson());

    }

    public String getJson() {
        String quoteUrl = "https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites";
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(quoteUrl);

        httpget.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = null;
        String aJsonString1 = null;
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            inputStream = entity.getContent();
            // json is UTF-8 by default
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }        TextView latCor = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Coordinates);


            result = sb.toString();
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
            aJsonString1 = jObject.getString("latitude");
            latCor.setText(aJsonString1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "can't execute http request", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception squish) {
            }
        }

        return aJsonString1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exception? It's probably because you're trying to do an HTTP call on the main thread.

Comment: can you elaborate more by posting the stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the exception, but my guess is, you're trying to do an HTTP call on your `main` thread, which is not allowed. I suggest you familiarise yourself with how Android handles long running tasks. You might find the following resources useful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtlRNNhane0
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/index.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Answer (score 0):

vkislicins seems right.

Also another exception you will get after the networking issue is that the response returned from https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites is a JSONArray but you try to parse it as JSONObject. You need to parse the response by

```
String latitude = null;
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
if (jsonArray.length() > 0) {
    latitude = jsonArray.optJSONObject(0).optString("latitude");
}
```